# What is vetoes in replication election in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

What is vetoes in replication election in MongoDB? It is not too clear from the documentation.
Doc link: [MongoDB vetoes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-elections/)

An appropriate example would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They work a lot like they do in real life.

Imagine, if you will, that your replica set represents the UN Security Council.

Each member has a veto that they can use to over come any majority vote by other members for a certain notion.

For example, a node in Russia could use their veto to stop any action, including the taking of primary, by the US/EU nodes.

Essentially a veto is a unmutable vote for that member but they can only be used in certain cases as you spotted: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-elections/#vetoes-in-elections